# bjam, how to find boost build

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, boost-build

I have **two** boost directories on my machine. One in /usr/ and one in /home/user/boost. How can I tell bjam to use only my local version in /home/user/boost. I have already set BOOST_ROOT to point to that directory, but bjam still tries to use the version in /usr/.

Edit: I figured out, that I can use a file boost-build.jam beside the Jamroot, with only one line telling bjam where to find boost.build:

```
boost-build $(BOOST_ROOT)/tools/build/v2 ;
```

But this is only suboptimal, since I have to create this file for every project. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question -- could you clarify in more detail?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. Should be clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to globally set the `BOOST_BUILD_PATH` environment variable. You should not need to mess with `boost-build.jam` for each project in that case.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. I already played around with BOOST_BUILD_PATH but forgot to set it to the build directory, only to BOOST_ROOT.